# Running vscode in WSL throws fatal error version mismatch between v8 binary and snapshot

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

Whenever I run the `code-insiders` command inside WSL, I get the below error:

```sh
~/dev ᐅ code-insiders .
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Version mismatch between V8 binary and snapshot.
#   V8 binary version: 7.7.299.13-node.16
#    Snapshot version:
# The snapshot consists of 327888 bytes and contains 0 context(s).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7fff0aac4bc0Illegal instruction
```

This has started happening spontaneously. I was using code-insiders for a while before in WSL without such problems.

Comment: Problem could be with VS Code server, to which Vs code connects each time, and there's no way to update it from our side, for me it's up to date already, I will wait for it to get resolved, till them I'm using PyCharm to connect to WSL

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was closing a running vscode insiders window. This ran the automatic update of vscode itself (it shows a small gray window with progress bar). After that, running `code-insiders .` in WSL terminal downloaded the new vscode server version and then I could start code-insiders in WSL normally.

Answer (score 0):

I solved same problem like this:
Open ubuntu, go to .vscode-server/.

```
cd /home/{username}/.vscode-server/
```

There was directory "bin". Delete this.

```
sudo rm -rf bin/
```

Now you can try open vs code

```
code .
```